Rate Exceeded Code Throttling - AWS Pipeline - Lambda Stage
I have a pipeline, in the code build stage, I have configured a stage called "Cache-invalidate", in this stage AWS Lambda function is trying to access CloudFront and invalidate files
but every time the build stage fails when Lambda is trying to invalidate the cache returning the below error

"Latest action execution message {"message":"Rate
exceeded","code":"Throttling","time":"2024-04-10T21:21:24.081Z","requestId":"d82276cf-bf5c-45e6-b4ca-26282cfa6e63","statusCode":400,"retryable":true}"

However, when I'm trying to execute this stage manually it's completing successfully, seems like the Lambda has been invoked too much during the pipeline process, how can I solve this issue??
Is creating a delay stage before the Lambda stage could help?

How many  times the lambda was executed? Read this https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudformation-rate-exceeded-error
